# How to delete associated rows with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to delete rows associated with a row in a table, without deleting the main row (thus can't use CASCADE).

This is the raw PostgreSQL query that does what I want to achieve with SQL. Is sequelize able to generate such query:

```
DELETE FROM session USING user WHERE session.user_id = user.id AND user.username = 'bob'
```

The model is (not including irrelevant columns):

```
create table user (
  id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4(),
  username text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

create table session (
  id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4(),
  user_id uuid NOT NULL references user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The association is defined in sequelize as:

```
Session.belongsTo(models.User, {
  foreignKey: "user_id"
});

User.hasMany(models.Session, {
  foreignKey: "user_id"
});
```

An alternative version of the query could be:

```
DELETE FROM session WHERE session.user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = 'bob');
```

But I think sequelize doesn't handle subqueries yet?

I tried something along the lines:

```
return Session.destroy({
  include: [
    { model: User, where: { username: 'bob' }}
  ],
  truncate: false
});
```

However, sequelize complains:

Error: Missing where or truncate attribute in the options parameter of model.destroy.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone gets here, this is how I "***delete associated rows with sequelize***": little help from the library:

1. Read the user from db (`Users.findOne({ ... })`)
2. call the method `setSessions(array)` provided by sequelize (the name depends on your model) which returns a promise.

```js
/** @param {string} username */
const clearUserSessions = async (username) {
  const userInstance = await Users.findOne({ 
    where: { username }, 
    include: ['sessions'] 
   })
   if (!userInstance) {
    /* user not found */
    return ...
   }
   await userInstance.setSessions([])
   /* removed every session from user */
   return ...
};
```

later:

```
try {
  await clearUserSessions('bob')
} catch(err) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
return Session.destroy({
    where: {
        '$users.username$': 'bob'
    },
    include: [{
        model: User,
        as: 'users'
    }],
});
```

Hope that helps. Try to reach me with comment.

Comment: Sequelize translates this as `DELETE FROM "session" WHERE "users"."username" = 'bob'`, then throws error `SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"`. As you can see in my question, the generated query is missing the `USING` statement (or an equivalent in non-PostgreSQL dialect).